# when use spock in android, raise "Test running failed: No test results Empty test suite."

Tags: android, testing, spock

I use this [repo](https://github.com/pieces029/android-spock), create android test with "Run > Debug ...> select AndroidTest", the test code is:

```
class MainActivitySpec extends Specification {

    @UseActivity(MainActivity)
    def activity

    def "test activity setup"() {
        expect:
        activity != null
        activity instanceof MainActivity
    }

    def "test layout"() {
        given:
        def button = activity.findViewById(R.id.main_button) as Button

        when:
        def buttonText = button.getText()

        then:
        buttonText == "Test"
    }
}
```

I get output:

```
Test running startedTest running failed: No test results
Empty test suite.
```

Comment: Why don't you use robospock?

Answer (score 0):

When you have your run configuration, click on 'Edit Configurations'. Replace "Gradle-aware make" with "Make" in "Before launch: Make, Activate tool window" at the bottom of configuration.

You may have to do this after each Gradle Sync.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you get that error message it's because you have a  compilation error in your code. Other than that, the only thing I see is that you extend `Specification`. When I started using this library (October 2016), the class you needed to extend was `AndroidSpecification`.